# Reusing ListAdapters and Lists

Tags: android, listview

I'm looking for an effective and reusable way of reusing lists of data in slightly different contexts.

**What I have is a list like the following:**

```
[Bitmap] PlayerName  
[Bitmap] PlayerName 
...
```

These are stored as ArrayLists that I get from Cursors and are parcelable so I can move them around as required.

The issue I have is that I want to re-use the Image and name but change info within the line.

**What I mean is this:**

When I show the players in the first list, I have a remove button that removes that player from the whole game.

In another list I also use a remove button but that's to remove them from a specific instance of a game.

In both these instances I've got a `Remove`button with the list, I use lazy hackery when I construct the ListaAapter to choose what the button does. The listitems themselves have no listener, just the button.

I now want to reuse the player list again, but have the whole items clickable (i.e. use the OnItemClickListener or some such) and then place a number next to them (in the order they were clicked).

I imagine I could add a TextView under the `Remove` box and wire it into the same thing and make the TextView and the Button visible as required but that seems like a pretty bad way to manage it.

How should I separate the presentation from the data in this instance?

**Potential solutions**

**1.** 
As per a suggestion on using layouts, I have a constructor like this:

```
public PlayerListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Player> players, GameInstance gameInstance) {
    super(context, R.layout.row_player_empty, players);
    this.context = context;
    this.players = players;
    this.gameInstance = gameInstance;
}
```

Would I add an int for layout to that constructor and then change my getView and onClick methods to use the layout to drive the different data sources?

**2.**

Another solution I've looked at is 'merging' layouts. Here I create a base 'player' and then for each set of additional UI elements I wrap the base into the additional elements as a new layout. This at least means I'm re-using the font/size/margins etc.

I'd probably rather overlay the elements a bit more dynamically but at least If I change the base style i'm doing it once rather than 3 times.

Comment: What I understand is, you want to show same data in other list, where on click of button you want to show a 'rank' as well, but as you click the button, button will vanish and only rank will show. Correct me wherever I missed it.

Comment: That's almost it. But essentially I want the same base data in 3 seperate lists, what I want is to interact with it 3 different ways, potentially overlaying new elements and changing behaviours each time in a re-usable way (as much as possible)

Comment: If you want to reuse the data, why don't you use database? or make the object static and parcelable and move it across whole app(second suggestion is more of a quick-fix).

Comment: This data does come from a database but at least two of the three adapters display the same players. I do parcel it around but don't need loaders at each stage. The issue isn't reusing the data, it's reusing the listadapters

Answer (score 0):

You can manage both list with different xml for it.
From fragment/activity, you can passs which kind of list view you are looking and on depneds on that, your xml out of 2 layout will inflate and you can set values.

In first case, you need just delete button clickable, so you can set listener on that only, in second case you need entire button clickable, so you can set onClickListner when you set that kind of list view xml.

As you have 2 cases:
in case 1, you should pass any boolean or enum kind value in constructor, so you can identify which kind of xml, I need to populate

And in getView() before inflating view, you should compare that value and depends on that, you should populate xml, like:

```
getView(){
   if(case1){
     View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.case_one_layout, null);       
     //set all values and listener on delete button as your require.
   }else if(case2){
     View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.case_two_layout, null);
     //here you can set listener on entire row as onItemclick from fragment.
   }
}
```

You can also manage with switch or other way as you like.

Comment: I've added a bit more detail to the bottom of my question, is that what you're suggesting?

Comment: Ok, my suggestion is like above.

Comment: I've partly adapted my program. I've made a composite listview with a "merge" and then merge it into two other RelativeLayouts with the requisite additional UI items. In the adapter I 'findViewById' and if it isn't null, I wire up the logic or listeners appropriately. 

Unfortunately this still isn't particularly adaptable and reusable - what if I want to create another 5 instances of the basic template. Is there not a better way? Should I leave a single class with the basic stuff and then extend in the extra elements in new classes perhaps?